# Symfony Gedmo Timestampable & sluggable not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

On a symfony 2.3 application I try to use gedmo fo timestampable and sluggable funtionnality.

Thois is how I installed it :

composer.json :

```
"gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "dev-master",
```

Update :

```
php composer.phar update
```

doctrine_extensions.yml :

```
services:
    gedmo.listener.sluggable:
        class: Gedmo\Sluggable\SluggableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]

    gedmo.listener.timestampable:
        class: Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]
```

config.yml :

```
imports:
    ...
    - { resource: doctrine_extensions.yml }
```

the entity :

```
namespace Too\EmployeeBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Too\EmployeeBundle\Entity\Employee
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Employee")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Too\EmployeeBundle\Entity\EmployeeRepository")
 */
class Employee
{
    ...
    /**
     * @var string $nomSlug
     *
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"nomSlug"}, updatable=true, separator="_")
     * @ORM\Column(name="nomSlug", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nomSlug;

    /**
     * @var datetime $cree_le
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $cree_le;

    /**
     * @var datetime $modifie_le
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $modifie_le;
    ...
```

I thought that this is all that I had to do but the behavior is strange now :

When creating the creation and modification date are filled up but not the sluggable field (nomSlug)

When trying to update I get this error :

```
This year is invalid
500 Internal Server Error - TransformationFailedException
```

If you need more code just tell me.

It would be kind to help me on this one ...

EDIT :

For the sluggable - you are right - my copy - paste error. This works now.

But I have still this 'This year is invalid' error When trying to update.
In fact the update is done but the timestampable fields are set to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in the database. And when the controler tries to render again the edit page with the updated data, the error comes because of the invalid date.

Now I thought that perhaps I should introduce hidden value of the timestampable fields ?!
Even if there is no logic for me in this.
But its not working anyway : the data are no more updated and in the flash notice I display I get just "flash.update.error" - so the form is not valid.

Here is this last code of edit.html.twig :

```
<form class="well" action="{{ path('employee_update', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(edit_form) }}>
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
    <div>
        {{ form_label(edit_form.nom) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.nom) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.nom) }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form_label(edit_form.email) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.email) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.email) }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form_label(edit_form.telephone) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.telephone) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.telephone) }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form_label(edit_form.actif) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.actif) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.actif) }}
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="too_employeebundle_employee_cree_le" name="too_employeebundle_employee[cree_le]" value="{{ entity.creele|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}">
    <input type="hidden" id="too_employeebundle_employee_modifie_le" name="too_employeebundle_employee[modifie_le]" value="{{ entity.modifiele|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}">
    {{ form_widget(edit_form._token) }}
...
```

Comment: Not sure if it cause of the problem, but `nomSlug` should be build from other fields (like title, publication date), not from itself.